# Is it compatible for browser

Tags: ionic-framework

Sorry for this very basic question but it's important to know.
I never used this kind of framework before and i am interested by trying ionic !
We can build html5/AngularJS apps with this framework, but is it only to generate native code for mobile apps or can we also use our code for the web app (should we maintain 2 different code ?) ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [browser support section](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/browser-support/)

> Ionic is focused on building **native/hybrid mobile** apps rather than
> mobile websites.

While you can get support from webkit, there isn't much support for other desktop browsers because, well it's just not what we want to focus on :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you recommend as the right approach for a project that has a mobile Ionic app AND a desktop browser app? Assuming the functionality is near-identical, would you suggest separate codebases anyway? Just separate templates and shared controllers?

Comment: Separate templates and shared controllers and factories

Answer (score 0):

It is browser competible, however not officially supported.